# JavaScript - Show More from DOM array

Tags: javascript

Trying to show some element on first render and when user click on Load More will show some more data and this will happen until all element show on each click;

```
const itemPerPage = 2;
```

Here is what I had tried with -

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const itemPerPage = 2;
    const AllItems = [...document.querySelectorAll('.item')];
    const btnLoadMore = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-loadmore')[0];

    if (itemPerPage > 0 && AllItems?.length > 0) {
        var firstRenderItems = Array.from(AllItems).slice(0, itemPerPage);
        if (firstRenderItems?.length > 0) {
            firstRenderItems.forEach(element => {
                element.style.display = 'block';
            });
        }
    }
    if (btnLoadMore && AllItems?.length > itemPerPage) {
        btnLoadMore.style.display = 'block';
    }
});
```

```css
.container{
  display:block;
  padding: 20px;
}
.item{
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  min-height: 70px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.btn-loadmore{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='item'>Content 1</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 1</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 1</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 1</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 1</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 1</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 1</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 1</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 1</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 1</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 1</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 1</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 1</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 1</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 1</div>
</div>
  <button class='btn-loadmore'>Load More</button>
</body>
</htmL>
```

Comment: And the question/problem is...? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: As @Andreas noted, OP needs to be clear on what exactly is the question / problem. It appears to me that the `Load More` button is expected to load 2 more items on each click - AND it is not working as per expectation. However, this is something that needs to be posted in the question. OP / @Daniel Smith - please confirm or clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show 2 items per page, one needs to add the button `onclick` handler using something similar to below:

**Code Snippet**

```js
const itemPerPage = 2;
const AllItems = [];

const loadItems = (currLastItem) => {
  AllItems.slice(
    currLastItem, currLastItem + itemPerPage
  ).forEach(
    el => el.style.display = 'block'
  );
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let currLastItem = 0;
    [...document.querySelectorAll('.item')].forEach(el => AllItems.push(el));
    const btnLoadMore = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-loadmore')[0];

    if (AllItems?.length > 0) {
      loadItems(currLastItem);
      currLastItem += itemPerPage;
    }
    if (btnLoadMore && currLastItem < AllItems?.length) {
      btnLoadMore.style.display = 'block';
      btnLoadMore.onclick = () => {
        loadItems(currLastItem);
        currLastItem += itemPerPage;
        if (currLastItem >= AllItems?.length) {
          btnLoadMore.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
    }
});
```

```css
.container{
  display:block;
  padding: 20px;
}
.item{
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  min-height: 70px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.btn-loadmore{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='item'>Content 1</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 2</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 3</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 4</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 5</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 6</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 7</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 8</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 9</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 10</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 11</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 12</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 13</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 14</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 15</div>
</div>
  <button class='btn-loadmore'>Load More</button>
</body>
</htmL>
```

Comment: load more still - showing at the end

Comment: your code not working when itemPerPage is greater than AllItems. Also load more not hide in that case too.

Comment: creating new post with more clarity

Comment: try now. answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let current = 2
  const AllItems = [...document.querySelectorAll('.item')]
  const btnLoadMore = document.getElementById('btn')

  if (AllItems.length > 0) {
    let firstRenderItems = Array.from(AllItems).slice(0, current);
    if (firstRenderItems.length > 0) {
        firstRenderItems.forEach(element => {
            element.style.display = 'block'
        })
    }
  }
  
  btnLoadMore.addEventListener('click', () => {
     if (AllItems.length > current) {
        current++
        if(current >= AllItems.length) btnLoadMore.style.display = 'none' 
        const list = Array.from(AllItems).slice(0, current)
        list[current - 1].style.display = 'block'
     }
  })
  
})
```

```css
.container{
  display:block;
  padding: 20px;
}
.item{
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  min-height: 70px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='item'>Content 1</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 2</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 3</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 4</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 5</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 6</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 7</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 8</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 9</div>
  <div class='item'>Content 10</div>
</div>
  <button class='btn-loadmore' id='btn'>Load More</button>
</body>
</htmL>
```

Comment: I feel OP was trying to render 2 items per page. Also, may be we are not required to loop through all elements from 0 to `current` each time (since most of those will already have display set to `block`?

Comment: It's not clear what the OP wants...  You are right about the loop

Answer (score 1):

Loads 2 items each time you click load more and hides the button once all items are loaded. I didn't see a reason why the items array couldn't be used to track the remaining hidden items so I used items.splice() instead of counting and comparing length to item count.

```js
var items = [];
const itemPerPage = 2;
var btnLoadMore;

function buttonToggle() {
  if (btnLoadMore && items.length) {
    btnLoadMore.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    btnLoadMore.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function loadMore() {
  if (items.length) {
    items.splice(0, itemPerPage).forEach(item => {
      item.style.display = 'block';
    })
  }
  buttonToggle();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  items = [...document.querySelectorAll('.item')];
  btnLoadMore = document.querySelector('.btn-loadmore');

  if (itemPerPage > 0 && items.length) {
    loadMore();
  }

});
```

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
}

.item {
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  min-height: 70px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.btn-loadmore {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='item'>Content 1</div>
    <div class='item'>Content 2</div>
    <div class='item'>Content 3</div>
    <div class='item'>Content 4</div>
    <div class='item'>Content 5</div>
    <div class='item'>Content 6</div>
    <div class='item'>Content 7</div>
    <div class='item'>Content 8</div>
    <div class='item'>Content 9</div>
    <div class='item'>Content 10</div>
    <div class='item'>Content 11</div>
    <div class='item'>Content 12</div>
    <div class='item'>Content 13</div>
    <div class='item'>Content 14</div>
    <div class='item'>Content 15</div>
  </div>
  <button class='btn-loadmore' onclick='loadMore()'>Load More</button>
</body>

</htmL>
```

Comment: Just a question, to help me understand better: `items = loadMore();`. Is this required? Within `loadMore()` the `items` array (global scope, I think) is being mutated (using `.splice()`) - so, do we need to return it from the method and assign back to `items`? Apologies - I'm still very new at js & only just learning.

Comment: No it is not required. Sorry about that. It was left over from trying something else. I'll update it, thanks for catching that.